# View Controller Resizes after Segue

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller, uistoryboardsegue

I can't seem to find a proper solution for this.  I'm running into a sizing issue when pushing (either via Segue or code) into a new VC.  I have the following:

Tab1: VenueTableVC -> VenueDetailVC -> CocktailDetailVC

Tab2: CocktailTableVC -> CocktailDetailVC -> VenueDetailVC

Tab3: UserProfileVC -> VenueDetailVC

Tab4: CocktailSearchVC -> CocktailDetailVC -> VenueDetailVC

I'm using storyboards with segues or code for these to push the appropriate view controller onto the navigation stack.  Every scenario is working well except for the one in Tab 2.  When going from CocktailDetailVC to a VenueDetailVC the size of the VenueDetailVC gets a reduced height.  Printing out to the console I can see that the appropriate height comes back from that view on ViewDidLoad but then prints a reduced height in ViewDidLayoutSubviews and ViewWillLayoutSubviews.  Is there something obvious I am not looking into?  I tried removing the segues, adding a segue back from the tableviewCell, adding a segue from the ViewController itself to the other view controller, tried pushing to the view controller with code and still get the same results.  One thing I did try was to put:

```
self.view.frame.size.height = UIScreen.main.bounds.height
```

in ViewWillLayoutSubviews in VenueDetailVC which appears to work but the table extends passed the tab bar at the bottom.  When I segue to that VC from other tabs it works fine.  Any ideas?

Comment: Would you be willing to post the code for your CocktailDetailVC & VenueDetailVC? I'll be much easier to help if I can see code.

Comment: Are you using the same iPhone model and storyboard? iPhone 6s and storyboard whit the 6s? Its not going to solve your problem, but will help me kwon whats wrong.

Comment: @DonovanKing I sure can.  Are there particular parts that are more helpful, they are both pretty big files but can put in some snippets that can be most helpful.

Comment: @JoséNeto I'm using storyboards with iPhone 7 and testing on an iPhone 7.  Both VC's are using Fixed simulator sizes.

Comment: See if you vc is like this http://imgur.com/a/QC4Ni

Comment: @HH887: All of the pieces having to do with view lifecycle: viewDidLoad, prepareForSegue, etc. A screen shot of your storyboard would also be useful.

Comment: @JoséNeto mine looks like this:  https://www.dropbox.com/s/165q8iqnvtuokpn/Screen%20Shot%202017-05-08%20at%202.34.15%20PM.png?dl=0

Comment: @HH887 did you tried to change?

Comment: @JoséNeto I did a few different combinations as well as the one in your screen and the best I got was the same.  The VC view height should be 667 (iPhone 7) but prints out 603 after layingout subviews still.

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out.  It was actually affecting the sizing of all VCs in the stack starting with CocktailTable.  I had some code in to remove the bottom navigation bar line:

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .any, barMetrics: .default)
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
```

Took that out of ViewWillAppear and it seems all set.